# Mutually exclusive select with same options in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, filter, ngfor

I'm trying to implement 3 select dropdowns that have the same array of objects as options. All the 3 dropdowns are mutually exclusive i.e. if I select one option in one dropdown it shouldn't show in the other two etc. This is my code:

home.component.html

```
<select formControlName="secQues1" id="securityQuestion1"
class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled>Select your first security question...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let question of securityQuestions" [value]="question.index">
    {{question.name}}</option>
</select>

<select formControlName="secQues2" id="securityQuestion2"
class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled>Select your first security question...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let question of securityQuestions" [value]="question.index">
    {{question.name}}</option>
</select>

<select formControlName="secQues3" id="securityQuestion3"
class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled>Select your first security question...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let question of securityQuestions" [value]="question.index">
    {{question.name}}</option>
</select>
```

This is my options array. There are about 15-20 entries here.

home.component.ts

```
securityQuestions = [{
    index : 0,
    name : "What was your childhood nickname?"
},{
    index : 1,
    name : "In what city did you meet your spouse/significant other?"
}]
```

I've tried using 3 different arrays and then splicing from 2 arrays but it doesn't work when someone changes the option (in this case the old option should get added back to other 2 dropdowns). 
Any suggestions?

Comment: The other two dropdowns are reflecting the same value because you have the same `value` binding for all 3 of them. Specifically, they all are bound to the `question.index` property, so whenever this property changes, the dropdown values will change. You need to bind the `value` property to different variables in order to make them independent.

Answer (score 1):

I would do what Octavian Mărculescu suggested. Three different arrays and just filter based on the selected value of the dropdowns.

- selectOneValue
- selectTwoValue
- selectThreeValue

I'm not sure if you want to use the ngModel to bind the selected values or if you will use another method.

**template.component.html**

```
<select (change)="selectChange($event, 1)" formControlName="secQues1" id="securityQuestion1" class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled>Select your first security question...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let question of securityQuestions1" [value]="question.index"> {{question.name}}</option>
</select>

<select (change)="selectChange($event, 2)" formControlName="secQues2" id="securityQuestion2" class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled>Select your first security question...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let question of securityQuestions2" [value]="question.index">
    {{question.name}}</option>
</select>

<select (change)="selectChange($event, 3)" formControlName="secQues3" id="securityQuestion3" class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled>Select your first security question...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let question of securityQuestions3" [value]="question.index">
    {{question.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**component.ts**

```
public selectOneValue;
public selectTwoValue;
public selectThreeValue;

public securityQuestions1 = []

public securityQuestions2 = []

public securityQuestions3 = []

constructor(private questionsService: QuestionsService){
 // get your questions promise or observable 

  this.securityQuestions1 = Object.assign([], securityQuestionsSource);
  this.securityQuestions2 = Object.assign([], securityQuestionsSource);
  this.securityQuestions3 = Object.assign([], securityQuestionsSource);
}

public selectChange($event, secQuestionArray: number) {

    if(secQuestionArray == 1){
        // filter 2 and 3
    } else  if (secQuestionArray == 2){
        // filter 1 and 3
    } else if(secQuestionArray == 3){
        // filter 1 and 2
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but like I said, if someone changes the selected option, the old option is also filtered out.

Comment: Did you try cloning the sourceArray?
this.securityQuestions1  = Object.assign([], securityQuestionsSourceArray);

Answer (score 0):

I would add another attribute to your `question` model, that is, `selectedIn`. So you would know it's already selected somewhere else, and which `<select>` it is.

```
securityQuestions = [{
    index : 0,
    name : "What was your childhood nickname?",
    selectedIn : 2
},{
    index : 1,
    name : "In what city did you meet your spouse/significant other?",
    selectedIn : 1
}]
```

Then, you can simply hide a given option if it's already selected elsewhere :

```
<select (change)="onSelectChange($event,1)">
    <option value="" disabled>Select your first security question...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let question of securityQuestions" [hidden]="question.selectedIn && !question.selectedIn==1" [value]="question.index" >
    {{question.name}}</option>
</select>

<select (change)="onSelectChange($event,2)">
    <option value="" disabled>Select your second security question...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let question of securityQuestions" [hidden]="question.selectedIn && !question.selectedIn==2" [value]="question.index" >
    {{question.name}}</option>
</select>

<select (change)="onSelectChange($event,3)">
    <option value="" disabled>Select your third security question...</option>
    <option *ngFor="let question of securityQuestions" [hidden]="question.selectedIn && !question.selectedIn==3" [value]="question.index" >
    {{question.name}}</option>
</select>
```

In your component :

```
onSelectChange($event, selectIndex){
    let questionIndex = Number($event.target.value) // 2 == question.index

    // Now update the securityQuestions array
    securityQuestions = securityQuestions.map( question => {
        // delete previous selection if any
        if(question.selectedIn == selectIndex) delete question.selectedIn
        // Mark the current question as selected in <select> n°1
        if(question.index == questionIndex) question.selectedIn = selectIndex
        return question
    })
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The hidden attribute will only be checked the first time not every time we select an option, right?

Comment: Well of course, you have to add some logic to define `selectedIn`. Use `$event.target.value`. I haven't developed the _whole_ solution, but you get the idea.

Comment: OK I have added the code in the component, to update the `securityQuestions` array. (Untested code, of course)

Comment: I tried something similar to that only but it doesn't work because the hidden directive is probably only checked the first time and not every time the array is updated.